# Syncing non-amazon ebooks via Whispernet to my kindle apps

Tags: sync, bookmarks, kindle

I was wondering, if there is a way to add my non-amazon purchased .mobi ebooks to the Kindle digital platform, so the books, notes and bookmarks are synchronized to all of my kindle apps and devices? Are there reader apps that would do something like this and available for PC and smartphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content should be synchronized between apps and devices if you send it to Amazon per mail (to `username@free.kindle.com`).

This synchronization is (or at least was) however considered to be buggy. So it might be necessary to delete and redownload the books to synchronize your reading progress.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronisation of Kindle personal documents has always worked fine for me. It doesn't work for PDFs though.

Be careful to only email the document to your @Kindle.com address once if you have multiple Kindle devices/apps. It will be delivered to whichever Kindle is associated with that email address, but will also appear in the Cloud or Archive section of your other devices. Use this to download it to the other devices. That way each device is seen to be reading the same version of that book. Emailing the book separately to each device means that each device is essentially reading it's own copy of the document, so the progress/bookmarks/notes etc. have no other devices to actually sync with.

Comment: My big complaint is that I cannot download ebooks from my Personal Documents to PC or to Mac based reader apps. It would be such a nice feature, if it could work that way...

Comment: Yes, that is a bit of a pain. They are also not viewable in the Cloud Reader.